# convert json text entries to a dataframe in r

Tags: json, r

I have a text file with json like structure that contains values for certain variables as below.

```
[{"variable1":"111","variable2":"666","variable3":"11","variable4":"aaa","variable5":"0"}]
[{"variable1":"34","variable2":"12","variable3":"78","variable4":"qqq","variable5":"-9"}]
```

Every line is a new set of values for the same variables 1 through 5. There can be 1000s of lines in a text file but the variables would always remain the same. I want to extract variable 1 through 5 along with their values and convert into a dataframe. Currently I perform these operations in excel using string manipulation and transpose. Here is what it looks like in excel -
[image]

How to do this in R? Much appreciated. Thanks.
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a package named `jsonlite` that you can use.

```
library("jsonlite")
df<- fromJSON("YourPathToTheFile")
```

You can find more info [here](https://www.import.io/post/3-easy-ways-to-get-your-data-into-r/).